# Ubuntu backup to only specific devices

Tags: authentication, linux, backup

I am looking into setting up a secure Ubuntu server with daily backups to two different external hard drives that will be swapped with the external hard drive that is stored in a safe deposit box.  The hard drives will be encrypted.

My question is, is there a way for Ubuntu to detect the serial number of the external hard drives and only do backups to hard drives that have a pre-approved serial number.

If there is a different, better method of authenticate the external hard drives, I am open for any advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the hard drive is encrypted, you need the *correct* password to decrypt it before it can be mounted for data transfer. That, in itself, is a form of authentication.

If you still need to verify the drive serial number, you can install `smartmontools`, then run the command (if your device is at sdb):

```
# smartctl -i /dev/sdb

smartctl 6.2 2014-07-16 r...
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Cobra 9900.1
Device Model:     SC8900112CD
Serial Number:    Q3JDOL14
```

Answer (score 0):

Mount with exact UUID to different location. Backup to that location.

Use blkid to get UUID.

```
blkid /dev/sda1
```